# Is a baseband signal single sided?

Tags: rf

I learned that a real-valued time domain signal has a conjugate symmetric frequency domain signal.

However, when I searched a *baseband signal* [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband), I feel that I am missing something. It shows a single-sided baseband signal.

[image]

I found another article [[2]](http://www.ece.iit.edu/~biitcomm/research/references/Other/Tutorials%20in%20Communications%20Engineering/Tutorial%209%20-%20Baseband,%20Passband%20and%20Amplitude%20Modulation%20(AM).pdf) distinguishing an *information* signal (figure 1, single-sided) and a *message* signal (figure 4a, double-sided). And a double-sided signal in figure 4a is what I've seen before.

[image]

[image]

Which one is right? I mean, both may be right. What am I missing?

Particularly, I want to apply this knowledge to a baseband of Wi-Fi signal (bandwidth: 20 MHz) before multiplied with local oscillator.

Comment: Both are right.    With only a single representation of a signal, it has a frequency spectrum symmetric around zero containing both positive and negative frequencies.  In another representation such as IQ, you can have a signal where the positive and negative components differ, ie, you can "block off" one side.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you represent a signal and what information you have about a signal.

Look at your first two drawings these only have **positive** frequencies. To make these signals double-sideband there would be **negative** frequencies !

What **is** a negative frequency ? Of course in reality all frequencies are positive but one can **mathematically** represent a negative frequency when you have information about the **phase** of that signal.

But if you only have a single wire with a signal (and a ground but let's ignore that for the moment) then how can you know what **phase** this signal has ?

The answer is that you can't. Phase is always **relative** so you need some reference or another signal to which you can compare the phase and know the phase. Actually the **phase difference** is all you need .

So you need two signals to make those negative frequencies. This a called a **quadrature signal**, often named I and Q. Read [this](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/essay/quadrature_signals.pdf) for a more thorough explanation.

If you would generate these I and Q signals you would have a spectrum containing **positive** and **negative** frequency signals !

Now when you want to wirelessly transmit such a signal you would multiply it with an RF (Radio frequency) carrier. The result of this is a spectrum with your original baseband signal folded around that RF carrier frequency, like in the 3rd drawing in your question.

This is because the multiplication (of BB and RF) results in **sum and difference** frequencies. If you have a BB spectrum with **only positive frequencies** (so no I and Q) you'd get a **symmetrical spectrum around the RF carrier**.

If you however did have a BB spectrum with positive and negative frequencies this positive frequencies and you mixed that in the proper way with a **quadrature mixer** then the negative BB frequencies would end up on one side of the carrier and the positive frequencies on the other side.

How is this usefull ? Well, having the same spectrum at either side of the carrier is not efficient, you're sending the same information **twice**. Or actually at the same time but at two different frequencies. Instead you could make those sides different, even transmit different signals (or no signal in SSB (Single Sideband)) and make optimum use of the available spectrum. Wireless systems like Wifi, GSM, UMTS they all do this.

Wifi uses a BB signal that can be as complex as 64bit QAM, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation). The bits to transfer can be represented in a [constellation diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constellation_diagram), note that this contains **phase and amplitude** information. The spectrum of such a QAM signal does contain negative frequencies so it is essential to process it in a quadrature capable transceiver. If you didn't cater for those negative frequencies, this QAM signal would be completely destroyed.

Comment: This is actually a bit backwards in its literal statements.  If you only have only one wire, you have *both* positive and negative frequencies and cannot tell them apart.  If you want to have *only* a positive or negative frequency, then you need to have two wires, ie, represent both I and Q.  Thus it would be more accurate to say "So you need two signals to make those negative frequencies **null**".

Answer (score 3):

It starts with Euler's formula for me: -

[image]

Where "i" is the square root of -1 and is often called "j" in electronics but there are more math pictures showing "i" than "j". So, what does this formula represent: -

[image]

The picture above shows \$e^{ix}\$ as a rotating vector due to the summation of cos(x) and i.sin(x). By using math trickery you can show that: -

\$sin(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2}\$

*The trickery is all about the expansions of \$e^{ix}\$, sin(x) and cos(x) and indeed Euler's formula (at the top of the page) can easily be derived this way*

So, we have "sin" in terms of two rotating vectors, \$e^{ix}\$ and \$e^{-ix}\$ and the difference is in the minus sign of the 2nd phasor - it implies a negative frequency: -

[image]

OK, don't be confused that "x" has changed to "\$2\pi ft\$ - these were the only pictures handy!

When both contrarotating exponentials line up you get the peaks of the sine wave (x2). The projections of the sine wave are onto the imaginary axis (90 degrees). A cosine wave would be projected onto the real axis.

In summary, the bigger picture is that a sine wave consists of two contrarotating vectors that represent a positive and negative frequency and although you don't need to worry about the negative one at baseband, when you modulate a carrier with a baseband signal you suddenly see two side bands.

Comment: IOW, "phase" is the culprit as expressed by +FakeMoustache.

Comment: @CynthiaAvishegnath IOW phase rotation is the culprit! Are they your lips?